# SQL Array Variable and If statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, t-sql

I have a historical table that keeps data on compliance issues. I want to create a graph showing each cluster's compliance status week over week. Unfortunately the query only shows non-compliant status with the date so I need to create a query that includes the dates where the clusters were compliant too.

What I think needs to happen is to create an array of the distinct date values 'D', then somehow match up the array values to the rows, if the row exists then show it, if it doesn't exist then create a row with the missing date and value of compliant.

Can someone help me out?

**Edit** SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fb3d/2

What the query shows now:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    D       |   Cluster      |      value        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/05/2014 |      T1        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/12/2014 |      T1        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/17/2014 |      T1        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/05/2014 |      T2        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/12/2014 |      T2        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/17/2014 |      T2        |  Non-compliant    |
+---------------------------------------------- --+
| 09/12/2014 |      T3        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/17/2014 |      T3        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

What I need it to look like:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    D       |   Cluster      |      value        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/05/2014 |      T1        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/12/2014 |      T1        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/17/2014 |      T1        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/05/2014 |      T2        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/12/2014 |      T2        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/17/2014 |      T2        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/05/2014 |      T3        |  Compliant        |
+---------------------------------------------- --+
| 09/12/2014 |      T3        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 09/17/2014 |      T3        |  Non-compliant    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Table structure an example data:

```
CREATE TABLE CLUSTER_INFO_HIST
    (

     CLUSTER_NAME varchar(255), 
     HA_ENABLED varchar(255),
     DATE_PULL varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO CLUSTER_INFO_HIST
(CLUSTER_NAME, HA_ENABLED ,DATE_PULL)
VALUES
('T1', '1','09/12/2014'),
('T1', '1','09/05/2014'),
('T1', '0','08/31/2014'),
('T2', '1','09/12/2014'),
('T2', '0','09/05/2014'),
('T2', '0','08/31/2014'),
('T3', '1','09/12/2014'),
('T3', '1','09/05/2014'),
('T3', '0','08/31/2014');

CREATE TABLE CLUSTER_INFO
    (

     CLUSTER_NAME varchar(255), 
     HA_ENABLED varchar(255),
     DATE_PULL varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO CLUSTER_INFO
(CLUSTER_NAME, HA_ENABLED ,DATE_PULL)
VALUES
('T1', '1','09/17/2014'),
('T2', '0','09/17/2014'),
('T3', '1','09/17/2014');
```

My query:

```
SELECT DATE_PULL, CLUSTER_NAME, HA_ENABLED FROM CLUSTER_INFO WHERE HA_ENABLED <> '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE_PULL, CLUSTER_NAME, HA_ENABLED FROM CLUSTER_INFO_HIST WHERE HA_ENABLED <> '1'
ORDER BY DATE_PULL, CLUSTER_NAME
```

Comment: Can you post the actual query ?

Comment: You need to post some details here before anybody has a chance at helping.

Comment: Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fb3d/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the existing table entries you would write:

```
Select DATE_PULL,CLUSTER_NAME,CASE when Coalesce(HA_Enabled,'0') =0 then 'Compliant' else 'NON-Compliant' end as value
from
( 
Select * from CLUSTER_INFO_HIST 
UNION
Select * from  CLUSTER_INFO 
) CI  
ORDER BY DATE_PULL, CLUSTER_NAME
```

If you need to provide  information within a date range even if not all clusters reported you might use :

```
Declare @Start dateTime='20140101'
Declare @End dateTime=GetDate()


;With CTE as ( -- create date table
Select @Start as aDate
UNION ALL
Select  1 + aDate
from CTE 
where  aDate+1 <@End
)
Select aDate,ALCLUSTER.CLUSTER_NAME,Coalesce(HA_Enabled,'0') as HA_Enabled
      ,CASE when Coalesce(HA_Enabled,'0') =0 then 'Compliant' else 'NON-Compliant' end as value
from CTE c

JOIN  --join all known CLUSTER_NAMEs 
( 
Select DISTINCT CLUSTER_NAME from CLUSTER_INFO_HIST 
UNION
Select DISTINCT CLUSTER_NAME from  CLUSTER_INFO c
) ALCLUSTER on 1=1

LEFT JOIN -- add HA_Enabled info
( 
Select * from CLUSTER_INFO_HIST 
UNION
Select * from  CLUSTER_INFO 
) CI on Convert(date,DATE_PULL,101)=c.aDate and ALCLUSTER.CLUSTER_NAME=CI.CLUSTER_NAME

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- prevent recursion break for CTE at 100
```

Comment: That's close but it is doing it for every date instead of just the distinct dates that are already in the table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fb3d/3